# LZ4 not compressing data (JavaBindings - org.lwjgl.lz4)

Tags: java, compression, lwjgl, lz4

I am using a Java-Binding for the popular LZ4 compression library, in my case *org.lwjgl.lz4* with the intend of compressing and managing a variety assets that way. I have working compression and de-compression of my custom format, verified by tests, which is basically able to:

- to put a bunch of files and a few bytes of metadata together, compress them and write them to an *asset*-file
- read all the bytes from an *asset*-file, decompress it and isolate the original file's data from there

So basically, an *asset* is basically just the raw bytes from a bunch of files put one after another, which then given to the compression.

When putting this into production however (aka not using trivial amount of bytes like in the unit tests), I noticed that **my implementation did not seem to actually make the files smaller**. While this is not my main goal, the fact that next to nothing was getting smaller is still suspicious, because at least some gains in respect to file size were expected on my part.

Overall, it comes down to this function

```
    private void compress(ByteBuffer uncompressed /* contains all byte content */, File output, boolean useHighCompressionFactor){
      ByteBuffer compressed = null;
      uncompressed.rewind();
      var numberOfBytesUncompressed = uncompressed.remaining();
      try {
          int numberOfBytesCompressed;
          compressed = MemoryUtil.memAlloc(LZ4.LZ4_compressBound(numberOfBytesUncompressed));
          if (useHighCompressionFactor){
             numberOfBytesCompressed = LZ4HC.LZ4_compress_HC(uncompressed, compressed, useMaxCompression ? LZ4HC.LZ4HC_CLEVEL_MAX : LZ4HC.LZ4HC_CLEVEL_OPT_MIN);
          } else {
             numberOfBytesCompressed = LZ4.LZ4_compress_default(uncompressed, compressed);
          }

          if (numberOfBytesCompressed <= 0) throw new IOError("Compression failed!");
          compressed.limit(numberOfBytesCompressed);
          compressed = compressed.slice();
          compressed.rewind();

          Files.deleteIfExists(output.toPath());
          var writeToFile = new FileOutputStream(output, false).getChannel();
          writeToFile.write(compressed);
          writeToFile.close();

          MemoryUtil.memFree(compressed);
      } catch (Exception e){
          if ( compressed != null ) { try { MemoryUtil.memFree(compressed); } catch (Exception ignored){ /* nothing */ } }
          throw new IOError("Failed to write Asset at '" + output.getAbsolutePath() + "' due to unexpected exception!", e);
    }
}
```

I consulted the docs as well as similar discussions here on StackOverflow but did not find anything wrong with above code. Again, I want to stress that compressing my files like that works and uncompressing them works as well and I recover the data perfectly, no matter what I put in.

But when I load the raw bytes taken from six different images of grass into *uncompressed*, which is like raw 18MB of RGBA-8 data in total, and then proceed to call this function afterwards, I am writing an asset to the drive that is still pretty much 18MB in size, even if both *useHighCompressionFactor* and *useMaxCompression* are true.

Yes, LZ4 is prioritizing speed over compression ratios but to me, it looks like its doing nothing and that implies I am doing something wrong.

Somebody got an idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "images"? Why do you expect "some gain"? If they are in any standard image format, like JPEG or PNG, then they are _already compressed_. They can't be compressed further in that form. You are then getting exactly the expected behavior.

Comment: This is true for every single image individually, yes. However, if you would put a number of JPEGs together into a ZIP, the resulting ZIP's size would still be lower due to the compression algorithms identifying common sequences of bytes, employing a dictionary and so on...

Moreover the 'uncompressed' data given as parameter is exactly that, uncompressed. In case of the images, which was just one example I used, we are talking raw 8-bit-per-pixel RGBA.

Updated the question to clarify.

Comment: Did you try to compress the raw image content with the `lz4` CLI directly, as a test to establish compression ratio expectation ?

Comment: Not yet, but that is a good idea.